# Jenkins/Hudson Java.IO error Unable to clean workspace - Windows server

Tags: continuous-integration, jenkins

I have a Jenkins/Hudson CI server, hosted on a Dedicated server (Kindly hosted by someone else). We have come to a problem which we cannot solve, and need help from people who may know solutions:

When we try to run a build, we get a Build Failed, and

```
java.io.IOException: Unable to delete C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\JumpPorts-2\workspace
```

Jenkins was able to create the files, so surely it can delete them? It is running as a service, and it is cloning the source (Maven - Java) from GitHub. This is on a windows server. I tested it on my VPS (Centos5) and it worked correctly, however due to it being a VPS, java does not run well with my other services, so i am unable to host it on there.

Full Error: http://pastebin.com/0tWVVdiH

Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jenkins jobs failing with "java.io.IOException: Unable to delete...", sugesstions on debugging?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6041968/jenkins-jobs-failing-with-java-io-ioexception-unable-to-delete-sugesstion)

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you are using the Maven project type.

The Maven project type can parse the pom on disk before building and while accessing the GUI. As a result when building on Windows, there is the chance that window's strict version of file locking can get in the way, marking a file as in use until absolutely every file handle is released.

One way to reduce this issue is to have the windows builds run on a slave node rather than the master (note that the slave node can be the same physical machine, but because the remoting channel is required to see the slave's filesystem, the file handles may not be as big an issue)

Another way to reduce this issue is to switch to a FreeStyle project with a Maven build step. Note that my personal preference is to avoid the Maven project type on pain of death. ;-)

Comment: Thanks for your help. We ended up removing Jenkins, and starting a fresh install. After a little hassle getting java re-installed also, we got it working. We installed it in C:\Jenkins\ this time rather than C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\ i think that may have caused some form of permission issue. But it is now up and running. Thanks for your help :) (We also use a slave on the same machine too)

Comment: Java doesn't like spaces in the path name. Also another issue is that Windows does not like very long paths. You can create them but deleting them can get tricky, so it could be that a very long path (8 \segments\ and/or 256 characters IIRC) was preventing the folder from being cleaned. Moving to a shorter path removed 1 segment and 24 characters and probably snuck you in under the window (no pun intended)